# Mentioning informal talks with current PhD students in SOP (USA PhD CS)

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am drafting my sop for CS PhD Programs. For this X college, I have had 3 short calls with their current PhD Students discussing about the program.

**Would mentioning this in the SOP (no names of the students involved) be helpful for the panel** or *should I avoid this?*

I would mention something like "After talking to the current students present there......"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any purpose for this, especially for mentioning their names. It doesn't actually say anything about your plans for study (and thereafter) other than that you want to do it.

Focus the space you have on what you intend to pursue and how you are prepared to be a success at it. Say something about longer term plans as well.

Keep the purpose of the SoP in mind when you write it. The CV covers past accomplishments, the SoP is about the future and how you plan to get there.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!